# Why numpy.where doesn't work with 'double' sliced arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't understand why 'double' slicing doesn't work with where?

```
>>> t
array([False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(t[:3])
(array([1, 2]),)
```

But:

```
>>> np.where(t[1:3])
(array([0, 1]),)
```

Comment: try `n + np.where(t[n:])[0]`

Comment: Yes @BiRico, or rather `n + np.where(t[n:])[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected output, because `np.where` doesn't know the full context of what you've sliced out.  Look first at the sliced arrays:

```py
In [384]: t[:3]
Out[384]: array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
        #        0       1      2

In [385]: np.where(t[:3])
Out[385]: (array([1, 2]),)

In [386]: t[1:3]
Out[386]: array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
        #         0      1

In [387]: np.where(t[1:3])
Out[387]: (array([0, 1]),)
```

In the second, you're skipping the first element; you start at `1`, but the first element is `0`:

```py
In [388]: t[0:3]
Out[388]: array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
        #        0       1      2

In [389]: np.where(t[0:3])
Out[389]: (array([1, 2]),)
```

---

If you want the index from the original array, you have to do some math as @BiRico suggests above, (but be careful and grab the first element from the tuple first)

```py
In [390]: n = 1

In [391]: np.where(t[n:3])[0] + n
Out[391]: array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Sorry, my question more specifically was how I can get the indices of the True booleans in the array?

Comment: @methane You are getting those, I've labled the indices in gray, and note that the numbers underneath the `True`s are the numbers returned by `where`

Comment: Yeah I was looking to find the indexing in the original array as @BiRico suggested above. Thanks!